# Three.js on ios and android performance?

Tags: three.js

Is that true three.js can only work as webview in ios and Android instead of calling native graphics API? In that case the performance will be very poor?

Comment: I recommend looking at the [three.js examples](https://threejs.org/examples/) on iOS/Android, and just its performance for yourself. I have successfully written small apps using Cordova, and only see performance issues when trying to display large data sets (many triangles/objects), which is equally a concern on desktop devices.

Comment: Thanks, will take a look, does it use webview?

Comment: Three.js is a wrapper API around WebGL which by definition only works in webview/browser. If you are very concerned about performances nothing can beat native apps but you will have to write platform specific code.